# Continuity of implicit function defined by a continuous and strictly monotone function

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions, implicit-function

Function $f:\mathbb R \mathsf x \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is given to be

1. Continuous everywhere.
2. Strictly monotone as per each free variable.
3. Such that the implicit function $g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$  with $f(x,g(x)):=c$ for c a real constant, is well-defined.

### Can it be deduced that g is continuous?

Note that $f$ is not given to be differentiable, therefore the Implicit Function Theorem cannot be used.

Comment: Try thinking about why $g$ must be strictly monotone, and from there, you can proceed by contradiction to get continuity.

Comment: I'll also say that it's actually sufficient for $f$ to be strictly monotone with respect to the second variable only, using just a couple extra arguments (since $g$ isn't necessarily monotone in that case).